# EE1 plugin that outputs data from third-party oracle database, can I cache?

Tags: php, plugin, ee1, performance, cache

I developed a plugin that pulls data from an oracle (oci8) database.

One function in the plugin returns hundreds of rows and the page takes about 5 seconds to load. I have caching turned on, so when you refresh the page, it takes .03 seconds to load.

I was wondering if there is any other things I could do to speed up or cache the data.

- I have optimized the sql scripts and use [oci_pconnect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-pconnect.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented apc cache.

I stored the data apc_add($key, $value, 600); and fetch it $value = apc_fetch($key);

Works like a dream.